# Vsftpd upload "permission denied" issue

Tags: server, vsftpd

Hi i have installed and configured ftp server on ubuntu 12.04.
`vsftpd.Config`

```
#anonymous_enable=YES
write_enable=YES.
```

when i drag and drops files to the Sever with filezilla, it fails:

```
****550 Permission denied.
Error:  Critical file transfer error.****
```

but when i try to do the same thing to another server on the Internet, it works just fine.
I even tried severe times to changes settings in the vsftpd.config file but it had the same problems respectively 
Help Thnks

Comment: Have you restart `vsftpd` like: `service vsftpd restart` after editing `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file? Sometimes it's forgotten :)

Comment: What are the permissions in the directory you are trying to write to?

Comment: @user109705 Have you solved it?